# Async urlfetch Http post on App engine using Future

Tags: java, google-app-engine, asynchronous, concurrency, httprequest

My goal is to rapidly make posts to a server from appengine(java).  I am attempting to do this using UrlFetchService.fetchAsync.  I have been basing my code after [this blog post](http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/).  I have been able to make the request using the code below, however I get some strange behavior:

```
private void futureRequests() {
    URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
    URL url = new URL("https://someserver.com");

    FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults();
    fetchOptions.doNotValidateCertificate();
    fetchOptions.setDeadline(60D);

    ArrayList<Future<HTTPResponse>> asyncResponses = new ArrayList<Future<HTTPResponse>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < postDatas.size(); i++) {

        HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST, fetchOptions);
        request.setPayload(postDatas.get(i).getBytes(UTF8));
        HTTPHeader header = new HTTPHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        request.setHeader(header);
        header = new HTTPHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDatas.get(i).getBytes().length));
        request.setHeader(header);
        header = new HTTPHeader("Authorization", "auth=" + authToken);
        request.setHeader(header);
        Future<HTTPResponse> responseFuture = fetcher.fetchAsync(request);
        asyncResponses.add(responseFuture);
    }

    for (Future<HTTPResponse> future : asyncResponses) {
        HTTPResponse response;
        try {
            response = future.get();
            int responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
            resp.getWriter().println("response: " + responseCode);
            logger.warning("Response: " + responseCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The strange behavior is that I get duplicate posts on the server, and according to my appstats page I use 10x-20x more urlFetches than what was added with the code above.  Below is my appstats screen:

[image: Appstats screen shot]

There are more urlFetch calls that could not fit on the screen.  It appears that the requests are still completing in a synchronous fashion(circled items), but there are many urlFetches that appear to go on at the same time.  My question is how am I getting all this calls to urlFetch when I only had 14 Future ??  Could the server be giving an error or 503 and urlFetch retrying until it goes through?  And how can I be getting 2 posts for each request??

I understand that I could use the task queue to do asyc request, however I am dealing with a relatively low number of request(20-100) and the cold start time of ramping up another instance would probably make this not a good option for my situation.  Can anyone explain this behavior or have experience with this?

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that you're doing more URLFetches than you think. Are you logging the number of futures you're creating somewhere? Have you looked at the traces for each RPC to see where it's coming from? Also, they're not synchronous - there's just a limit on how many outstanding requests will execute at the same time.

Comment: Are you getting redirects? Those are followed by default. IMO the only explanation would be that you are having a redirect loop.

Comment: @NickJohnson looks like the obvious answer was the right one.  I was indeed sending more than request than I thought.  One misplaced curly bracket caused the futureRequest() to be called inside of a loop instead of outside...simple correction, now it works like a champ and dramatically reduced the time it takes to complete the process.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a mistake in my code that was causing my app to make more request than I thought..